# Select de produtos por categoria PAI, com produtos cadastrados na categoria filho

Tags: mysql

Seguinte, fiz as seguintes tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE produto (
  codigo        INT UNSIGNED      NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nome          VARCHAR(128)      NOT NULL,
  url           VARCHAR(255)      NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (codigo)
);

CREATE TABLE categoria (
  codigo INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nome   VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  url    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  parent INT UNSIGNED          DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (codigo)
);

CREATE TABLE produto_categoria (
  cod_categoria INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  cod_produto   INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (cod_categoria) REFERENCES categoria (codigo),
  FOREIGN KEY (cod_produto) REFERENCES produto (codigo)
);
```

Como vocês podem perceber, a tabela categoria, possui o campo parent, que serve para atribuir a categoria pai.

No entanto estou com o seguinte problema:

> Select dos produtos são realizados pela URL da categoria que pertence.

Quando faço com a categoria  da tabela produto_categoria OK.

No entanto quando faço o Select pela categoria pai, e retornado null, pois o produto não pertence diretamente a categoria pai.

Exemplo:

Produto -> Atum (**codigo 1**)

Categoria -> Comida (**codigo 1**) -> Enlatados (**codigo 2**| **parent 1**)

Produto_Categoria -> cod_categoria (**2**) | cod_produto (**1**)

> Quando faço o select pelo **enlatados**, fica OK, mas gostaria que quando seleciona-se pela categoria **Comida**, aparece-se os produtos das categorias filho!

Fiz esta view, para o select, no entanto ele so retorna da categoria que o produto esta vinculado.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_site_produtos AS
SELECT
  p.codigo, p.nome, c.url,
FROM
  produto p
  LEFT JOIN produto_categoria pc ON p.codigo = pc.cod_produto
  LEFT JOIN categoria c ON pc.cod_categoria = c.codigo;
```

E faço a consulta da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT * FROM view_site_produtos WHERE url = '';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa pegar todos `ids` dos filhos que tem aquele pai para assim fazer o `select`. Isso é possível através de um `subselect`, no exemplo eu usei a coluna nome, porém você pode mudar o `where` para a coluna url que o `select` não deve ser afetado.

```
SELECT * FROM categoria c
    JOIN produto_categoria pc ON pc.cod_categoria = c.codigo
    JOIN produto p ON p.codigo = pc.cod_produto
WHERE c.codigo IN (select c_filho.codigo from categoria c_pai
                        join categoria c_filho on c_filho.parent = c_pai.codigo
                     where c_pai.nome = 'Comida');
```

Comment: Você me salvou, muito obrigado!